# How to achieve "clear" for bottom of div, not just left and right

Tags: css, alignment

I'm displaying a list of links for voting, similar to [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/).  I want the following layout for each link:

[image]

The gray boxes highlight the four divs for each link listed.

**The key thing I need to do is get the "other text" div to be left-aligned with the link headline text.**

I could define the width of the rank and arrow divs (the two little boxes), of course, and then indent the other text div accordingly.  But this implementation has some downsides relative to my specific needs -- which I won't go into -- and more importantly, I just feel like there should be a more elegant way to achieve this.  Something like a clear bottom for the rank and arrow divs, or maybe a property of the link headline div that tells the following div to appear directly below it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a combination of the answers given by @Adam and @Czechnology, and use a list to display the content, and put the `Link headline text` and `other text` boxes into a single parent div. Like so:

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="headlines">

  <li class="news-item">
    <div class="rank">9</div>
    <div class="arrow"><img src="arrow.png" /></div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2><a href="foo.html">Link headline text</a></h2>
      <div class="additional-content">other text</div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="news-item">
    <div class="rank">10</div>
    <div class="arrow"><img src="arrow.png" /></div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2><a href="foo.html">Link headline text</a></h2>
      <div class="additional-content">other text</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Style:**

```
ol.headlines {
  display:block;
  list-style-type:none;
  list-style-position:outside;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div {
 border:1px solid #00F;
}


 ol.headlines .rank, ol.headlines .arrow, ol.headlines .content {
  float:left;
}

.news-item {
  clear:left;
}

ol.headlines h2,
ol.headlines .additional-content {
  display:block;
}
```

You can find a sample of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/DEWtA/

Note that you'll need to alter the CSS to your needs with regards to the size of the divs and such.

Comment: It works fine without doing a list, I just clear:right on the wrapper div for the "headline" and "other" divs.  Is the motivation for turning it into a list just conceptual clarity?  Admittedly, it does seem like a good design decision, even if the code is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tim Koelkebeck - The code is perfectly fine without using a list, but (assuming it is a set of news headlines), you are creating a list, so it is semantically better to represent that list properly in HTML using `<ol>` or `<ul>` tags, much for the same reasons that we're not supposed to use `<table>` elements for non-tabular data.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just put the two right containers in one?

```
<div class="rank">9</div>
<div class="arrow">arrow</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="row1">Link headline text</div>
  <div class="row2">other text</div>
</div>
<br class="clear" />
```

style:

```
.rank, .arrow, .content {
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: left;
}
```

---

*EDIT*: [Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHVYU/1/)

Comment: This seems like the logical solution.

Comment: Depending on HTML structure these divs reside in, that might be one more useless div. :)

Comment: "_Useless_" is relative. This pattern follows the logical flow.

Comment: Why the br tag rather than clear:right on the content div?  The latter works for me just the same.  Is it that the br tag approach is more cross-browser compatible?

Comment: @Tim, I don't think `clear: right` is going to help you in the sample I've provided since all the elements are floating _left_ so if it "works" for you, it is for some other reason.  You could set `clear: left` on the `.rank` div, that would work too. No special reason for `<br />` it's just a way I'm used to do it (it makes breaking obvious even without looking in the CSS).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

It seems that all four boxes for each item are in one bigger box (li maybe), so I would use:

```
<li>
  <span class="num"></span>
  <span class="upvote"></span>
  <span class="main">main text</span>
  <span class="add">more text</span>
</li>
```

and

```
.add { clear: both; float: right; }
```

**Solution 2**

Other solution would be `padding` on parent of each group of four and then negative `margin-left` together with `float: left` on number and upvote links.

Anything better can be tailored to your needs, but we need to see HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide a wrapper element for the link headline text and the other text? Then float the wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/H3qPt/

**HTML**

```
<div class="linkblock">
    <span class="score">100</span>
    <span class="arrow">^</span>
    <div class="linkdata">
        <div class="linkurl">Link headline</div>
        <div class="linktext">Other text</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Some of this is just for demonstration.

```
.linkblock .score,
.linkblock .arrow,
.linkblock .linkdata {
  float: left;
}
.linkblock br {
  clear: both;
}

div, span {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
}
div.linkdata {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can contain the those two things into divs and then for the left div with the voting stuff, label the div with a class, "vote", and have the following CSS:

```
.vote {
  margin: 0 0 100%;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work like a charm.

Caveat: Doesn't work well with responsive design :(

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would probably be to wrap 'link headline text' and 'other text' within a 'div' and use 'overflow: hidden;' on it.